# forward connection to another?

Tags: linux, unix, networking, routes, ssh

I need to ssh twice to get to my work computer remotely. First I have to ssh to the office local server. Then I have to ssh to my local computer (ip address). There is no direct way. Is there a way I can just log in once and it will somehow make the connection for me? I want to make a shell script and use rsync to make backups to my house. I believe rsync can only handle the one ssh connection. Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

You want to make use of the **ProxyCommand** option of ssh. Here is an example that uses one machine to connect to another.

You can add the following to your **~/.ssh/config** file.

```
Host viatunnel
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/inside_server_rsa
  ProxyCommand ssh -i ~/.ssh/proxy_server_rsa user@gateway.mynetwork "nc inside.mynetwork 22"
  user myself
```

This will connect first to **user@gatwway.mynetwork** and use that to make a connection to **myself@inside.mynetwork**

Now typing: **ssh viatunnel** will connect using this configuration.

The ProxyCommand line basically runs 'nc' on the first hop of your connection and establishes a tunnel to port 22 on the second server. Then the outside ssh uses that to connect.

See **ProxyCommand** here at the [openssh manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the tool you are looking for is called [**ProxyTunnel**](http://proxytunnel.sourceforge.net)